# Gitlab + Sonar - there aren't an author in the Issue tab

Tags: angular, .net-core, gitlab, sonarqube

There aren't an author in the Issue tab on some projects. Some another projects have the author. What a reason? Is it settings in sonar ui or code?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen an assigned author somewhere near the red arrows. Anyway, issues can be assigned manually to a person or automatically by using SCM, which uses git blame. However, there are some caveats, such that person's email must match in Git and Sonarqube.